# do while loop not working? Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I trying to make a do while loop that will keep looping till x either equals y or x equals 7
Here's the code:

```
else if(y == 4 || y == 5 || y == 6 || y == 8 || y == 9 || y == 10){
    System.out.println("Value point is: " + y);

    int x = rollDice();
    do{
        System.out.println("Roll again: " + rollDice());
        x = rollDice();
    }
    while(x != y || rollDice() != 7);

    if(x == y){
        System.out.println("You Win!");
    }
    if(x == 7){
        System.out.println("You Lose");
    }
    return;

}}
```

This is what an output looks like from it:

```
Dice roll is: 9
Value point is: 9
Roll again: 2
Roll again: 6
Roll again: 6
Roll again: 4
Roll again: 7
Roll again: 11
Roll again: 8
Roll again: 9
Roll again: 2
Roll again: 5
Roll again: 6
Roll again: 8
Roll again: 5
Roll again: 11
Roll again: 5
Roll again: 2
Roll again: 9
Roll again: 6
Roll again: 3
Roll again: 8
Roll again: 8
Roll again: 8
Roll again: 4
Roll again: 7
Roll again: 10
Roll again: 6
Roll again: 5
Roll again: 9
Roll again: 4
Roll again: 7
Roll again: 4
Roll again: 2
Roll again: 8
Roll again: 8
You Win!
```

Obviously 8 does not equal 9, and since there was a seven near the beginning it should have said "you lose" I just don't where I'm going wrong on this?

Comment: what's up with that part `|| rollDice() != 7);`? you are throwing a bunch of `rollDice()`, but most of the time you don't affect it to x, making it effectively useless.

Comment: That was just a mistake I made, I fixed it once you guys pointed it out. Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT:*

Please change the loop to this:

```
do{
    x = rollDice();
    System.out.println("Roll again: " + x);
}
while(x != y && x != 7);
```

You should only call rollDice() once per iteration. You were calling it 3 times each go-round. Also, the || needed to be changed to &&.

Comment: I changed it, thanks for noticing that. But it still doesn't stop when x = y or x = 7.

Comment: It's a program to play craps so if the rollDice is 7 or 11 it prints win and if it is 3,2 or 12 it prints lose.

Comment: See the EDIT to my answer. You should only call `rollDice()` once per iteration. You were calling it 3 times each go-round.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like where you wrote

```
x != y || rollDice() != 7
```

you wanted

```
x != y && x != 7
```

(If you said you wanted to loop until "x either equals y or x equals 7", then you really want &&, not ||, in your condition.)